# Read out mails from exchange with php and display it as a website

Tags: php, email, web, exchange-server

I would like to read the mailbox on an exchange with the help of PHP.
This Exchange is our domain.

The idea is to display the report mails of the backupruns on a website.

Only certain messages should be displayed, they should be filtering by using to subject of the mail.

Example: Backup Exec Alert: Job Success (Server: "SERVER") (Job: "JOB")

In the subject is the word "Job Success", if it finds "Job Success" it should be displayed on the site including server and job ofcourse. The date and time should also displayed and it only have to show the last mails from the 24h.

I hope you understand my question and you can help me out.

Here is what I got, I don't know if this is right.

```
<?php

$server = "{webmail.domain.xx}INBOX";
$user = "...";
$passwd = "";

$mbox = imap_open($server,$user,$passwd) or die("Could not open Mailbox - try again later!");

...
?>
```

Comment: Well does it connect or does it show the error message? Try to access the mails, with the imap command. I'm not sure you can filter on the server though. You might need to retrieve all mails and filter in your code.

Comment: how do I can check if it connects or not?
I'm new with php

Comment: Well what das imap_open retun?

Comment: I use this code:
`<?php
 $host   = 'webmail.domain.xx';
 $port   = '993';
 $server = '{' . $host . ':' . $port . '}';
 echo "server: ".$server."\n";
   
 $email  = 'name@domian.xx';
 $passw  = 'mypaswrd';
   
 $mbox = imap_open($server, $email, $passw);  
 echo "imap result: ".$mbox."\n";
 imap_close($mbox);
?>`

And then I became this output:
**Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {webmail.domain.xx:993}**

Comment: Okay I found out why: I have to set a Flag "imap/ssl/novalidate-cert". Now the connection works.

Comment: i have copy your code but still found the same error??? also informed that our mail server does not support imap/pop3...can you please help me to fixed this error..